# How to assign default values and variable statement assignment

Tags: c++

My professor says my code is missing these two aspects

- must init variables with default values first   -2
- your program is missing variable assignment statements  -3

However I am not sure what they mean.

I have set my int variables to a default of 0 but I do not know how to assign new values to them.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <iomanip>
 #include <string>

 using namespace std;

 int main ()
 {
    string theatre = "AMC Universal CityWalk";
    string present = "Presenting";
    string movie = "A Star is Born Encore";
    string show = "Show time";
    string time = "PM";
    string day = "Date";
    string room = "Theatre";
    string rating = "PG-13";
    string admission = "Adult Admission";
    string ad = "Don't forget to get your free small popcorn"
        " with 4 tickets or more!!!";
  /*
    int timeHour = 3;
    int timeMinute = 20;
    int dateMonth = 04;
    int dateDay = 12;
    int dateYear = 2019;
    int roomNumber = 10;
    float price = 12.75;
  */
    int timeHour = 0;

    int timeMinute = 0;
    int dateMonth = 0;
    int dateDay = 0;
    int dateYear = 0;
    int roomNumber = 0;
    float price = 0.0;

    cout << "\t\t" << theatre << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t" << present << endl;
    cout << "\t\t" << movie << endl;
    cout << show << ": " << timeHour << ":" << timeMinute << " " << time;
    cout << "\t" << day << ": " << dateMonth << "/" << dateDay <<     "/" <<
        + dateYear << endl;
    cout << room << ": " << roomNumber;
    cout << "\t\t\t" << rating << endl;
    cout << admission << ": $" << price << endl;
    cout << ad << endl;


}
```

I need to print out the values that are in the commented section but I cannot figure out how to assign the int variables new values.

Comment: `int timeHour = 3;` is a variable declaration with initialization. `timeHour = 0;` is an assignment of variable. The 2nd must appear after first because assignment cannot be done when variable is not yet declared. `int timeHour = 3; /* some stuff left out */ int timeHour = 0;` is a re-definition of variable which is prohibited (compiler error). It is not allowed to define a variable twice in the same scope (roughly speaking). So, do you see what's wrong when you uncomment the rest of code?

Comment: You should ask them what they mean. And if you need to assign a value, just assign it. `variable = value;`

Comment: It seems like you are asking people to speculate on what your professor means by those statements. It looks to me like you are assigning values to the integers, so you probably need to talk to your prof to find out what they want and then ask a specific question about what you are struggling to accomplish.

Comment: Btw. `std::string` is a class with a default constructor. Hence, `std::string rating;` is declaration with default construction. `int` is a so-called [POD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_data_structure) type. POD types do not provide default construction. Hence, `int hour;` declares a variable but leaves it uninitialized. (It may have any value.) When POD types are used in C++, initializing them always is a habit to prevent uninitialized variables.

Answer (score 0):

first read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)
and if you want set new value to variables do like this:

```
int timeHour = 0;
timeHour = 10;
```